# How should I use the <If> directive in .htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, xampp, .htaccess

I'm trying to add a conditional statement using Apache's If directive in my .htaccess file.

I have referenced this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if but it doesn't elaborate much / give many examples. Two incomplete examples it gives are:

```
<If %{REQUEST_METHOD} IN GET,HEAD,OPTIONS>
```

and

```
<If "$req{Host} = ''">
```

So I've tried to add this to my .htaccess file:

```
<If %{SERVER_PORT} IN GET,HEAD,OPTIONS>
   #nothing here yet
</If>
```

But I keep getting **Error 500** when I try and load the page. This is on my local install, and it was working fine previously (or if I remove that code). I believe I have `AllowOverride All` set up globally, and the context for the If directive should let it be present in .htaccess ("Context: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess").

Can someone give me some examples of how to properly use the <If> directive, or some guidance as to why it is not working for me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, that means that Apache has logged something to your error log.  What does it say?  Also, your test for `SERVER_PORT` in `GET,HEAD,OPTIONS` doesn't make any sense (`SERVER_PORT` is going to be the number port number on which the request was received).

Comment: Thanks, larsks. Looks like I am running apache 2.0 which does not support the <If> directive. Maybe I need to look into upgrading to 2.3. At least this explains why there are no examples anywhere (b/c the feature is so new). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<If>` directive is only available in Apache 2.4+ and not 2.2 or earlier.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

Documentation not present in 2.2:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#if

Answer (score 20):

`<If>` is only available in Apache 2.4+, so firstly make sure that you have that version.

## Examples

```
# Compare the host name to example.com and redirect to www.example.com if it matches
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
  Redirect permanent "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</If>

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /regex/">
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</If>

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/regex/including/slashes/#">
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</If>
```

## Alternatives to `<If>`

There are a few other solutions for doing conditional statements in Apache 2.2 if you're still stuck with that.

- You can set environment variables via:

  - Apache configuration
  - `SetEnvIf`
  - mod_rewrite's `RewriteMatch`
- Then you can perform conditional statements using

  ```
  <IfDefine MyEnvironmentVar>
     ...
  </IfDefine>
  ```

Example:

```
# Set environment variable if we're on staging site
SetEnvIf Host staging ROBOTS_NOINDEX

# Set environment variable if we're within a specific folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/app/webroot/files/ ROBOTS_NOINDEX

# Send custom header if environment variable is set
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" ENV=ROBOTS_NOINDEX
```

Comment: Test but not work! in the document from apache, `<IfDefine>` directive only parse at startup and the `parameter-name` is only can passing by command promp using `httpd -Dx=y`

Comment: Your "Alternatives to If" were working fine for me, nice example.