# Set header based on %{REQUEST_URI}

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am trying to set a header based on the URI of a particular page.

I access a page using chrome.
Inspect element and see that my URI header is giving the value /bst/index.html
Now in my Apache config , I want to set a Header to Yes if my %{REQUEST_URI} is equal to /bst/index.html
This is what I am doing :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/bst\/index\.html [NC]
Header set X-Akamai Yes
```

The above config is not working and is setting X-Akami for all the pages I am visiting on the web page.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 5):

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/bst/index\.html#">
Header set X-Akamai Yes
</If>
```

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) and [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

Comment: Thank You Florin. But is "m#^/bst/index\.html#"" this whole a regex ? I mean whats the purpose of m & # in this all ?

Comment: Apologies. I missed out on the fact that there was a second document too. 

I tried the solution you provided. 

Gives me the below error when I restart Apache :
    Syntax error on line 66 of /tools/conf/ssl.regular.conf:
       Header has too many arguments
I will check different solutions.

Comment: Try the first syntax, it definitely works.

Comment: i have same issue, but when i use `<If>` directive then it give me `500: internal  Error`, what should i do ?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: Dear thanks for you quick response.error_log is empty ..!

Comment: The `<If>` directive was only added in Apache 2.4 . There are some alternatives to it for older versions: https://serverfault.com/a/698192

Comment: So you downvoted the answer because you are using an unmaintained version of Apache Web Server? Nice!

Answer (score 0):

%{REQUEST_URI} will probably just match the last path in the URI (index.html). You probably want to try with %{THE_REQUEST} instead:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#^/bst/index\.html#">
  Header set X-Akamai Yes
</If>
```

Comment: `THE_REQUEST` expands to the full browser request line, including the request method, so this will **never** match. [Check here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Answer (score 0):

For me %{THE_REQUEST} worked better liked this (I changed the regex of "Nestor Urquiza":

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m# /bst/index\.html#i">
  Header set X-Akamai Yes
</If>
```